# Accessing a URL using a loop

Tags: java, url

I have created a web application, and hosted in on the server. Now I want to create a java program which will access (or "hit") the URL of my application in a loop, so that I can check how much load can my web application can handle. Also, the program should be able to tell me when the URL was successfully accessed, and when it wasn't.

I tried executing it without using a loop:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://example.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e: " + e.toString());
    }
```

But, I got this error:

```
e: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No  subject alternative DNS name matching example.com found.
```

Comment: There is no secure http for this url.

Comment: You need to import the certificates in your client keystore before you can hit the https url.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be https, you can use a command in a CMD window like so: `ping -n 50 -l 1024 example.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use,

```
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

to connect to `https://`

something like (note, handle resource closing, exceptions etc left on you)

```
final URL url = new URL("https://example.com");
final HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String input;

while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

However there are lots of tool available to load test it

Answer (score 0):

you are just getting a stream from url, but obviously this url is using HTTPS, so you need a "Public Key" imported to your client application. otherwise the client and server won't be able to communicate with each other.